# Scala can not resolve symbol ++

Tags: scala

I am currently doing an assignment from the Odersky course on Coursera. I have defined the following method:

```
def encode(tree: CodeTree)(text: List[Char]): List[Bit] = encodeAcc(tree, tree , text, List())

def encodeAcc(tree: CodeTree, treeAcc: CodeTree, text: List[Char], bits: List[Bit]): List[Bit] = (treeAcc, text) match {
  case (Leaf(char, _), t :: ts) => {
    if(char == t) bits ++ encodeAcc(tree, tree, ts, List())
    else null
  }
  case (Fork(left, right, chars, bits))  => encodeAcc(tree, left, text, bits ++ List(0)) ++
                                            encodeAcc(tree, left, text, bits ++ List(1))
}
```

Where

```
 type Bit = Int
```

However, I am getting 2 errors on the last two lines, on `bits ++ List(0)` and `bits ++ List(1)` saying `Cannot resolve symbol ++`.

Why can't I append the lists?

Comment: How is Fork class defined? "bits" in the matching expression overrides "bits" which was an argument, is it done deliberately?

Comment: Also, ++ has O(n), complexity, where (n) is the length of your List. You would be better off, performance-wise, with prepending the elements to the list and inverting the result in the end.